# Can't get pass login screen flutter web

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-web

I've been working with Firebase auth and Firestore and **everything** works on Android emu, but when I lunch in Chrome, I can't get pass login,
I've imported all the code Firebase gave me for index.html :

```
 <body>
   
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
     <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
     <script src="/__/firebase/7.21.1/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
   
<!-- Initialize Firebase -->
<script src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>
<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyCtfc......IstukN0Ci_mc",
    authDomain: "prettya1..91e.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://prettya.com",
    projectId: "prettyan..",
    storageBucket: "prettyanki-....com",
    messagingSenderId: "17870...",
    appId: "....."
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

</script>
  <script>
    if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {
      window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        navigator.serviceWorker.register('flutter_service_worker.js');
      });
    }
  </script>
  <script src="main.dart.js" type="application/javascript"></script>
  
</body>
```

login :

```
import 'package:PrettyAnki/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:PrettyAnki/shared/constants.dart';
import 'package:PrettyAnki/shared/loading.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Register extends StatefulWidget {
  final Function toggleView;

  Register({this.toggleView});
  @override
  _RegisterState createState() => _RegisterState();
}

class _RegisterState extends State<Register> {
  List<Color> gradientcolors = [Color(0xFFcb2d3e), Color(0xFFef473a)];
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();
  final _formkey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  bool loading = false;

  //text field sate
  String email = "";
  String password = "";
  String error = "";

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              flexibleSpace: Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topLeft,
                        end: Alignment.bottomRight,
                        colors: gradientcolors)),
              ),
              centerTitle: true,
              elevation: 0.0,
              title: RichText(
                text: TextSpan(children: <TextSpan>[
                  TextSpan(
                    text: "Pretty",
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.white,
                        fontFamily: "Courgette",
                        fontSize: 25),
                  ),
                  TextSpan(text: "Anki", style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white))
                ]),
              ),
            ),
            body: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 50),
                child: Form(
                    key: _formkey,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Welcome,",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.redAccent),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration:
                              textInputDecoration.copyWith(hintText: "email"),
                          validator: (val) =>
                              val.isEmpty ? "Enter an email" : null,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              email = val;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              hintText: "password"),
                          validator: (val) => val.length < 6
                              ? "Enter a password 6+ characters long"
                              : null,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          obscureText: true,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              password = val;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        TextFormField(
                          decoration: textInputDecoration.copyWith(
                              hintText: "confirm password"),
                          validator: (val) {
                            if (val != password) {
                              return "Passwords don't match";
                            } else {
                              return null;
                            }
                          },
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                          obscureText: true,
                          onChanged: (val) {
                            setState(() {
                              password = val;
                            });
                          },
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        RaisedButton(
                            color: Color(0xFFcb2d3e),
                            child: Text(
                              "Sign Up",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                            ),
                            onPressed: () async {
                              if (_formkey.currentState.validate()) {
                                setState(() {
                                  loading = true;
                                });
                                dynamic result =
                                    await _auth.registerWithEmailAndPassword(
                                        email, password, "");
                                if (result == null) {
                                  setState(() {
                                    error = "please supply a valid email";
                                    loading = false;
                                  });
                                }
                              }
                            }),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          error,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 20,
                        ),
                        FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              widget.toggleView();
                            },
                            child: Text(
                              "Already have an account ? Sign In",
                              style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red[400]),
                            ))
                      ],
                    ))),
          );
  }
}
```

I searched on internet but there are very few tutorials for Firebase Flutter web and they don't seem to have this problem.

sometimes i get this error :

```
Error: MissingPluginException(No implementation found for method
startListeningAuthState on channel plugins.flutter.io/firebase_auth)
    at Object.throw_ [as throw] (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:4465:11)
    at MethodChannel._invokeMethod
    (http://localhost:55251/packages/flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart.lib.js: 
   409:21)
    at _invokeMethod.next (<anonymous>)
    at http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:37106:33
    at _RootZone.runUnary (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:36960:58)
    at _FutureListener.thenAwait.handleValue
    (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:32047:29)
    at handleValueCallback (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:32594:49)
    at Function._propagateToListeners (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:32632:17)     
    at _Future.new.[_completeWithValue] (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:32475:23)   
    at async._AsyncCallbackEntry.new.callback
    (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:32497:35)
    at Object._microtaskLoop (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:37221:13)
    at _startMicrotaskLoop (http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:37227:13)
    at http://localhost:55251/dart_sdk.js:32849:9
```

pubspec :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
  firebase: ^7.3.0
  
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  provider: ^3.1.0
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.0.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  flip_card: ^0.4.4
  carousel_slider: ^2.2.1
```

Comment: Hi, for security reasons, you should remove the apiKey value you posted. And is there any errors you get? Please offer more details about the issue.

Comment: There is no login screen in the code you shared. Please make sure that your question contains the [minimal, complete/standalone code that reproduces the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it drastically increases the chances that someone can help.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen thanks, i added the codes

Comment: @alexandrum, thanks for the advice, i sometimes get an error, i added it in the post

Comment: @PaulCbt Could you please also add the versions of SDK and firebase are you using?
I suspect the versions are not compatible.

Comment: @alexandrum do you mean in pubscpec.yaml ? if so :  dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.14.0+5
  cloud_firestore: ^0.12.9+4
  firebase: ^7.3.0
  
  firebase_core: ^0.4.0
  provider: ^3.1.0
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.0.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  flip_card: ^0.4.4
  carousel_slider: ^2.2.1

Comment: I had a look over [pub.dev](https://pub.dev/publishers/firebase.google.com/packages) and it seems your versions are kinda behind, try to update them (if it is possible). As you can see on the link, you have the latest firebase core but not on auth and others.

Comment: @alexandrum, thanks a lot, that was it! everything working now

Comment: You welcome mate. You should always look for the latest versions or version compatibilities between used libraries. ;)

Answer (score 1):

so the solution is, you need to update dependencies, my pubscpec now :

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter

  

  # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
  # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.3
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  firebase_auth_web: ^0.3.0+1
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase: ^7.3.0
  
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  provider: ^3.1.0
  curved_navigation_bar: ^0.3.3
  flutter_spinkit: ^4.0.0
  json_annotation: ^3.0.1
  flip_card: ^0.4.4
  carousel_slider: ^2.2.1
```